Rigging a pupil as a separate mesh
I'm having difficulty setting up an eye rig for a model where the pupils are a separate mesh. I want to be able to move the pupils, but only confined within the eye istelf. I've tried using the shrinkwrap modifier, but I can't find a setting where the pupil doesn't become severely deformed.


hello could you please share your file or at least show some screenshots?

Just added the blend file

Maybe first remove the shapekeys of the eye, align the mesh with the world XYZ and put the origin at the center:

Give a Shrinkwrap constraint (not modifier) to the eye with the eye as Target, activate Align to Normal (X):

Move the eye on Y and it will stick to the eye. Maybe give a Subdivision Surface modifier to the eye and parent the pupil to the eye. Result:


This mostly works, however I can't seem to get it to work with an armature.

You need to parent the eyes to the head bone
